# Data not being added to database despite having conn.commit()

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

first time posting here so I apologize for poor formatting. I recently starting to use SQLite3 and have looked at tutorials/instructions but I can't seem to get it working, specifically, adding data doesn't commit it to the database.

```
import random, sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('card.s3db')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE card(
    id INT,
number TEXT,
pin TEXT,
balance INT DEFAULT 0
);""")
conn.commit()

card_number = ''.join([str(i) for i in number_list_copy])
pin = ''.join(["{}".format(random.randint(0,9)) for i in range(0, 4)])
cur.execute("INSERT INTO card (number, pin) VALUES (?, ?)", (card_number, pin))
conn.commit()
```

I omitted some code but essentially card_number is just a string. When I execute

```
cur.fetchall()
```

or

```
cur.fetchone()
```

I get an empty list or *none* respectively. I've also tried different ways to insert the data and gone through some threads on here.

Thanks!

Comment: do you query some data before `fetchall()` ? e.g. `cur.execute("select * from card")
`

Comment: @bwt no I don't. I don't do anything in between regarding the database, I've also tried putting `fetchall()` right after `commit()` but it's still empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `insert` modifies the data but has no result.

To get data from the database you have to use a [`select`](https://sqlite.org/lang_select.html) query.

For example :

```
cur.execute("SELECT number, pin FROM card")
the_data = cur.fetchall()
```

As a side note, you probably want to make the `id` column a primary key :

```
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
```

Comment: Thank you so much :)